# Does it make sense to use node's `cluster` in horizontally-scaled cloud environment?

Tags: node.js, cloud, cluster-computing, horizontal-scaling

In modern cloud environments like AWS, GCP, Azure, or anything that supports Kubernetes, it's pretty easy to setup multiple instances of a node service, load balance them, and get pretty good performance. Are there any good reasons for using nodejs's `cluster` module to run multiple subprocesses on a single service instance? It seems like the extra complexity is unnecessary, because you can just spawn additional single-process instances to handle more traffic.

Comment: Did the answer below helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal and vertical scalability are two different concepts. As you said, it may not make sense in a cloud environment, but if you think about an on-premises type of software, in which for some reason you have a limited number/size of nodes, you need to make the best use of them, vertically speaking.

Comment: @JohnSyrinek, did it help somehow?

Comment: Thanks Fabio - sorry for the late response. I'm looking for any justifications for using specifically in a cloud environment. You may be onto something with efficient use of resources, but I'm not sure running subprocesses would be a whole lot more efficient than multiple containers, and if you consider load balancing implementations, it may even be slower.